# Difference of GPS status on Android OS

Tags: android, android-location, android-build

I have been experiencing a different behavior while executing my application in different Android OS.

I have LG-E612 with Android 4.0.3 and my application uses GPS for location updates, once the GPS gets fixed with satellite, the GPS status icon on the Status Bar remains constant through out while running the application. My application request for GPS location updates after every 2 seconds.

While the same application I executed, on Android 4.0.4 it seems that everytime I request for location update, the GPS icon on the status bar appears and dis-appears again during the 2 sec interval.

I trying to find why there is two different behavior in Android OS. Anyone could link the revision change in the two different OS ir any idea...

Or If anyone could explain under what circumstances the GPS icon on the status bar appears, dis-appears or blinks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that behavior affecting the functioning of your application? Or are you curious to know what that is so?

Comment: I am curious to know and understand why that is so?

Comment: Well actually, both 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 are treated as the same [API Level 15](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) and the [Difference Report](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/15/changes.html) does not have any specifics for the changes listed. Unless I am missing something entirely different. It could be LG's implementation that may have changed. Of course I haven't gone in the details in their entirety. But on the top of it, I don't see any changes.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, Just to clear that Android 4.0.3 is in LG-E612 and Android 4.0.4 is in HTC Desire Z.
I am still unclear how to approach confusion. Is there any discussion that states the GPS status bar icon visibility statuses.. Means under what conditions it appear/disappear/blinks?